# Why the checkthree() method is not asking for input ? why it was terminating prematurely?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inputTesting {
    public void checkone(){
        String input="Hello Word";
        Scanner s=new Scanner(input);
        while (s.hasNext()){
            String word=s.next();
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        s.close();
    }
    public void checktwo(){
        System.out.print("Enter the line: ");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            String k=s.nextLine();
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(k);
            while (sc.hasNext()){
                String word=sc.next();
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            sc.close();
            break;
        }
        s.close();
    }
    public void checkthree(){
        System.out.print("Enter the line which should combine using '_': ");
        Scanner sy=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sy.hasNextLine()){
            String sk=sy.nextLine();
            Scanner sn=new Scanner(sk);
            sn.useDelimiter("_");
            while (sn.hasNext()){
                String word=sn.next();
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            sn.close();
            break;
        }
        sy.close();
    }
}
class inputs{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        inputTesting it=new inputTesting();
        it.checkone();
        it.checktwo();
        it.checkthree();
    }
}
```

Steps i have tried:

1. Removed the new line print from checktwo() method i.e: System.out.println(word);
2. added extra : sy.nextLine() method, to consume if any lines were there previously before entering the checkthree() while loop.

Both the points were not worked.

Solution i have tried is : passed the input directly from it.checkthree("This_is_my_name_"); and hardcoded checkthree() method too , and it worked corrcetly.

Expecting:

Why my actual code is not working ? due to multiple scanner objects? even tough i need a solution using scanner object only, please provide your recommendations.